# Unable to specify the alignComponent for an ImageButton

Tags: android, imagebutton

I'm trying to set my TextView to the left of an ImageButton, but I can't seems to find this option.

I was expecting to use something like android:layout_alignLeft, but this option is missing.

I've tried to google the issue, but couldn't find any relative results.

[image]

Without it my TextView overlaps the ImageButton and I want to avoid it.

**UPDATE**

The full xml code is too complex, but here is the important part of it:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/frameLayoutBalanceClosed">
    <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/button_edit_nickname"
            android:id="@+id/card_closed_control_editNickname" />
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/card_closed_description_nickname"
            android:layout_margin="8dp" android:layout_gravity="left"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your full XML code?

Comment: Can you replace the FrameLayout or is it important?

Comment: What would you suggest to use instead of the FrameLayout?

Comment: Well, the way the FrameLayout works is that it overlays items on top of each other. Depending on your application, I'm not sure what would be the best, but generally the most used is LinearLayout or RelativeLayout

Comment: What is your application using a FrameLayout for?

Comment: I use it as an alternative to the JPanel, which I couldn't find in the Android SDK

Comment: Oh ok, actually android has many things similar to JPanel, they're just kind of hard to find. Just give me a sec to write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html). You can specify your TextView to the left of your ImageView with it's specifications. Your code would look something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imagebutton1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imagebutton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The reason FrameLayout isn't working is because it's purpose is to overlay items on top of each other, which wouldn't work at all!

If that isn't what you're looking for, you could also use a [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) in which items are arranged in columns.

Comment: Aha! So the issue is not with the ImageButton but with the parent layout! Thanks a lot :)